# OpenSSL error in Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, digital-ocean

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol):
```

I got that error in my Rails on digitalocean. Yesterday it works good but lately this afternoon I got that error. I google some solution but nothings happen. What makes this error?

Comment: You're going to have to give more context than that. For example, add the rest of the stack trace if necessary, or show the code that generates the problem. That could indicate you're connecting on the wrong port.

Comment: I had this error when connecting to an imap server with ssl turn on whereas the server didn't expect ssl connection. Maybe you should turn off ssl ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Seeing a bare error gives us very little to go on in trying to figure out what code is breaking on your machine. Can you please edit your question (don't post code in comments because the formatting is awful) and add: the code that you are running that causes this error, the relevant section of your logfiles and preferably the stacktrace. You say yesterday it worked, but today it doesn't? what changed between yesterday and today?